# graphql trouble accessing items in object

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I am still trying to learn graphql and I am having trouble accessing items that are within an object in the database. In my client side code the data for id and createdAt shows up just fine it is just when I add the object that I get the error:

```
Expected Iterable, but did not find one for field Users.profile
```

I am not sure what my code is missing:

resolver:

```
 Query: {
    getUser(root, args, { userId }) {
      const {id } = args;
      const user = User.findOne({
          id
        });

        return user;
    }
  },
```

schema

```
const User = `
type User{
 id: String!
 createdAt: Date
 profile: [Profile]
}

type Profile {
 name: String!
 email: String!
}

extend type Query {
  getUser(
    id: String!
  ): User
}
```

How I am calling it in my client code:

```
const getUser = gql`
  query getUser($id: String!) {
    getUser(id: $id) {
      id
      createdAt
      profile {
        name
        email
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

This is how it looks in the MongoDB database:

```
user{
  _id: "22222"
  createdAt: 11/22/2018
  profile:{
    name: "Chris"
    email: "chris@emample.com"
  }
}   `
```

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone in future I had to set my objects to JSON to get it to work.

```
const User = `
type User{
 id: String!
 createdAt: Date
 profile: JSON
}

extend type Query {
  getUser(
    id: String!
  ): User
}
```